# why I am getting the phonenumber return by the contentprovider NULL

Tags: android

I  have added name and phone number via using content provider , when i want to display the content which i have added i am able to see only the Name but phone number it returns NULL , for reference iam publishing my Code ,

```
private void displayContacts()
{
    String[] columns = new String[] {People.NAME,People.NUMBER};
    Uri mContacts = People.CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor mCur = managedQuery(mContacts,columns,null,null,null);
    if (mCur.moveToFirst())
    {
        String name = null;
        String phoneNo = null;
        do 
        {
         name = mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex(People.NAME));
         Log.e("---CURSOR POSITION","--VALUE OF CURSOR--"+mCur.getColumnIndex(People.NAME));
         phoneNo = mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex(People.NUMBER));
         Log.e("---CURSOR POSITION","--VALUE OF CURSOR--"+mCur.getColumnIndex(People.NUMBER));
         Toast.makeText(NativeContentProvider.this, name + " " + phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } while (mCur.moveToNext());
     }
}
```

i have try to display the COLUMN INDEX VALUE also in LOG i get the value as

```
01-06 05:49:50.234: ERROR/---CURSOR POSITION(421): --VALUE OF CURSOR--0

01-06 05:49:50.234: ERROR/---CURSOR POSITION(421): --VALUE OF CURSOR--1
```

am i doing something wrong please correct

Comment: Have you tried using "Phones.CONTENT_URI" instead.I guess People.CONTENT_URI lists only the primary phone number while Phones.CONTENT_URI lists all the phone number pertaining to a contact.

Comment: how to update iam unable to update the phonenumber

Comment: hey manish thanks for your helpful sugesstion and it works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are interested in getting contact id or number from contact list only and if you wanna get for result so use start activity for result, do two step

step 1 make intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,Phone.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

step 2 startactivityforresult

```
   public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
            switch (reqCode) {
                    case (PICK_CONTACT):
                     if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
             Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                  if (c.moveToFirst()) {
           Stringname=c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Phone.NUMBER))+":c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexrThrow(People.NUMBER))";                       
                              txtContacts1.setText(name);
                                    }
                            }
                            break;
            }
    }
```